# FullCalendar, поменять временные интервалы (по вертикали)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Подключил плагин [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/). Как можно задать массив временных интервалов, что бы были примерно такие отрезки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В документации не смог найти.